# Can Apache Lucene replace ETL tools for text processing

Tags: apache, lucene, compass-lucene

I got a flat file extract of 15GB and its spec which helps to identify each row record and how to split each row to gather required information. I am planning to make use of ETL tools, because I thought text processing of this bulk file cannot be achieved in java. But I came to read about Lucene now. Now am really confused. Following are my doubts:

1. Can Apache Lucene can process a 15GB flat text file without memory issues.
2. What is the performance benchmark for 15GB flat file to read each row, identify the identifier and based on the identifier split the row data and load it into mapped db.
3. Can I use Apache Lucene for this task OR go for ETL tools?

Comment: you really want to process 15 Gb in one go? what do you want to do with this file in ETL, give some examples, plz

Comment: Hi, I want to read each row, identify the identifier and based on the identifier split the row data and load it into mapped db.

Comment: may be I'm wrong, but that's completely didn't sound to me like a task for Lucene